# Data Structures Array Problem: Cannot find the first repeating item

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

I am new to data structures and algorithms and I have a problem.

we have two arrays and I want to return first repeating item:
eg:
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr2 = [6, 2, 3, 1, 8]

in the above case first repeating item is 2.

This is the solution if we use hash table:

```
def find_same_hash(arr1, arr2):
    dictitonary = dict()
    for i in range(len(arr1)):
        dictitonary[arr1[i]] = i
    for j in range(len(arr2)):
        if array2[j] in dictitonary:
            return arr2[j]
        else:
            dictitonary[arr2[j]] = j
    return "Undefined"

result = find_same_hash(arr1, arr2)
print(result)
```

But what I need is the solution in Array:
And this is what I am doing:

```
def find_same(arr1, arr2):
    for i in range(len(arr2)):
        for j in range(len(arr2)):
            if arr1[i] == arr2[j]:
                return arr1[i]
    return None

result = find_same(arr1, arr2)
print(result)
```

But the problem is that it is returning 1. 1 is repeating but it is not the first one to repeat.

Comment: Those are lists, not arrays!  Do you mean, the first item in Array2 that is also present in Array1?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the order of the lists for iteration. That way you find the first (or 'earliest') item in `arr2` that appears in `arr1`, not the opposite:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr2 = [6, 2, 3, 1, 8]

def find_same(arr1, arr2):
    for i in arr2:
      for j in arr1:
        if i == j:
          return i
    return None

print(find_same(arr1, arr2))
# 2
```

Comment: The inner loop could be replaced with `if i in arr1`

Answer (score 0):

Your specific problem is that you're checking them in the wrong order

```
def find_same(arr1, arr2):
    for i in range(len(arr2)):
        for j in range(len(arr1)):
            if arr1[j] == arr2[i]:
                return arr1[i]
    return None

result = find_same(arr1, arr2)
print(result)
```

There's a simpler option..

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [6, 2, 3, 1, 8]

def first_duplicate(list1,list2):
    for n in list2:
        if n in list1:
            return n
```

Using a generator is very neat and tidy:

```
print(next(n for n in list2 if n in list1))
```